# ¿Cerrar las preguntas de anteriores ediciones de Translation Golf para que no inunden la "front page" del stack?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, preguntas-cerradas

Como algunos habréis visto, esta mañana le he pegado un repaso a los tags de todas las preguntas de [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) para indicar el idioma del texto de esa edición.

La parte buena, espero, es que así podremos atraer a usuarios que conozcan otros idiomas aparte del inglés.

La parte mala es que ahora la lista de "preguntas con actividad reciente" está copada por las preguntas del juego (14 en total) y queda bastante mal: parece que somos un stack que solo se dedica a jugar. ¡Lo siento!

Para solucionar esto, había pensado en hacer una pequeña edición sobre todas las preguntas con actividad "real" en esta última semana, de manera que vuelvan a salir arriba; pero, aparte de ser un peñazo, no creo que sea lo correcto. Entonces, se me ha ocurrido que quizá sería viable cerrar las preguntas antiguas, de esa manera ya no saldrían en la lista ¿correcto?

¿Cómo lo veis?

EDIT: Me he permitido ponerle un flag a las 12 primeras, referenciando esta misma pregunta. Si al final se dejan abiertas, me contarán como flags no útiles, pero sobreviviré jajaja :D

Comment: La próxima vez (y para estar seguros) primero publica en meta, consideramos todos juntos qué acción tomar y luego actuamos. Yo no me preocuparía tanto por esa lista (que está mostrando lo que debe: actividad reciente), y en lugar de hacer "edits superfluos" para dejar las cosas como estaban, qué tal buscar post muy antiguos que necesiten algún edit? A por las medallas "excavator" y "archaeologist"!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cerrar las preguntas no solucionaría el problema: una vez cerradas, seguirán apareciendo en la página inicial. Solamente dejan de aparecer las preguntas con puntuación menor o igual que -4 (y menor o igual que -8 en Meta, [referencia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/209901)) o si están bloqueadas.

La idea de añadir la etiqueta [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) puede tener su peso, pero habría sido bueno consensuarla aquí en Meta previamente. Te animo a abrir una pregunta aparte para discutirlo, pues si la aceptamos deberemos aplicarla a -posiblemente- centenares de preguntas.

En cuanto a lanzar *flags* para que se cierren las preguntas, incurre también en un error conceptual: los moderadores podemos cerrar una pregunta con un solo click, pero reservamos este superpoder para los casos especiales. Es siempre mejor que la comunidad sea la que actúe de forma coral. Por eso, usar un *flag* como atajo no acaba de encajar con la idea general de moderación. Entiendo y valoro que hayas pensado en nosotros para actuar rápido y mejorar la experienciai del sitio, eso sí :) Pero tal y como [comentó Diego](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2662/cerrar-las-preguntas-de-anteriores-ediciones-de-translation-golf-para-que-no-in/2663#comment4371_2662), ¡mejor consúltanos antes!

Verás que he declinado uno de los flags. No me gustaría declinarlos todos, pues te dejaría un registro muy feo. Ahora tenemos dos opciones: o marcarlos todos como "helpful" sin hacerles nada, o dejarlos allí por si quieres retractarlos y que así no te computen. Además, para futuros casos ten en cuenta que un solo flag es suficiente: indícanos el caso detalladamente y nosotros ya nos pasearemos por la lista de preguntas.

Resumiendo:

- Antes de crear una etiqueta que pueda implicar mucho jaleo, ¡discutámoslo!
- Cerrar una pregunta no la saca de la página de inicio.
- Usa los flags de modo que nos hagan hacer cosas que un usuario normal no pueda.

Eso sí, debo reconocer que me ha hecho ilusión ver 11 flags pendientes, el récord creo que estaba en tres.