# ¿Debemos usar las etiquetas "inglés" o "italiano"?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, idioma-de-la-publicación

Tal y como comentó walen en [¿Cerrar las preguntas de anteriores ediciones de Translation Golf para que no inunden la "front page" del stack?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2662/1674), hace unos días añadió la etiqueta [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) e [italiano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italiano) a todas las preguntas de [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) de uno u otro idioma.

¿Qué os parece esto? ¿Deberíamos usarlas?

Cosas a tener en cuenta (en mi opinión):

- Si la usamos, ¿en qué casos? ¿En todo lo relacionado con esos idiomas? Esto implicaría añadir [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) en un 80% de las preguntas de [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n), por ejemplo.
- ¿Qué beneficio aporta tener estas etiquetas? El [privilegio de crear etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) indica algo vagamente:

> Las etiquetas más comunes ya existen en un sitio maduro. Siempre debes favorecer las etiquetas existentes. Sólo crea nuevas etiquetas cuando sientas que puedes argumentar que tu pregunta cubre un nuevo tema que nadie más ha preguntado antes en este sitio.

Dado que somos un sitio en estado beta, esta discusión es aún muy pertinente.

Comment: Discusión relacionada en [latin.se]: [When to use the “English” tag?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/312/1896)

Comment: @walen no hay prisa, veamos qué opina el resto. Ahora la publicación aparece en "hot meta posts" por lo que debería verla más gente. En cuanto a mi postura: tu respuesta, así como [el debate en Latin.SE](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/312/1896) me hacen verle posibilidades. Al fin y al cabo, buscamos maneras para agrupar preguntas, pero filtrar traducciones con una etiqueta extra no parece demasiado necesario, pues ya podemos buscar [`[traducción] catalán`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btraducci%C3%B3n%5D+catal%C3%A1n) directamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personalmente y tras darle una pensada, sigo pensando que **es útil** disponer de etiquetas para identificar los idiomas de las preguntas, al menos **para los idiomas "minoritarios"** en lo que al sitio respecta, como pueden ser el **italiano, francés, portugués, alemán, vasco, catalán, japonés, astur,** etc.

Esto permitiría que **usuarios con conocimiento de esos otros idiomas puedan identificar más fácilmente preguntas** sobre la relación del español con estos; preguntas que, seguramente, no muchos otros usuarios podrían responder.

En cuanto al tag **para el idioma inglés, reconozco que resulta superfluo**: por las características de StackExchange podemos dar por supuesto que todas las preguntas de tipo [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n) van a estar relacionadas con el inglés, salvo indicación en contra (¿mediante un tag? ;).

Si os parece, propongo eliminar el tag [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) y mantener los de otros idiomas.

---

EDIT: a propósito de la [discusión enlazada por fedorqui](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/when-to-use-the-english-tag), en el sitio de Latin SE puede verse que estos tags se usan para las preguntas que tratan sobre la relación entre el latín y el lenguaje del tag.
Bajo ese punto de vista, se me ocurre por ejemplo que [mi pregunta sobre la relación entre la palabra estribor y las palabras *starboard* y *estribord*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21453/13628) podría tener los tags [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) y [francés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/franc%c3%a9s).

Con esto quiero decir que me sigue pareciendo buena idea que existan dichos tags, si no para marcar los idiomas de las traducciones (que puede ser engorroso y discriminatorio), sí al menos para identificar preguntas especialmente vinculadas a dichos idiomas, tal como hacen en Latin SE; así como para mostrar a los usuarios que esto no es solamente un sitio de español-inglés, inglés-español.

Comment: De acuerdo con lo que planteas en tu edición, ¿podrías identificar alguna otra pregunta que podría beneficiarse de estas etiquetas? Intento imaginar su uso en preguntas no de traducción y me cuesta encontrar ejemplos que la hagan factible (con factible me refiero a que engloben un mínimo de ¿10? preguntas).

Comment: Aceptemos pues esta respuesta. Probemos qué tal se da. Es trabajo de todos ahora vigilar que se utilice correctamente, ¡todos firmes! :)

Comment: Aceptada esta respuesta (y para facilitar ese uso responsable), sería prudente añadir una descripción a las etiquetas ya creadas: [tag:inglés], [tag:italiano]. Por seguir esta línea, he creado [tag:euskera] **solo para la pregunta de [tag:translation-golf]**, que es donde fueron creadas las otras. Esta, de hecho, puede necesitar sinónimos como "vasco o vascuence", que puedo crear, aceptar y fusionar si hace falta, pero creo que antes de crear etiquetas a lo loco para otros idiomas hemos de ver qué pasa con estas. Avisadme si hacen falta "mod tools" para cualquier tarea.

Answer (score 0):

Propongo eliminarlas.

La idea de tener etiquetas como [italiano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italiano) para que la gente pueda suscribirse y actuar sobre preguntas que es una ventaja el conocimiento sobre ese idioma no es mala, **pero**:

1. Nos obliga a tratar el inglés de forma distinta a las "lenguas minoritarias" (entendiendo por "minoritarias" su escasa presencia en relación al inglés en nuestros posts). Este caso particular es mala señal.
2. No hay prácticamente preguntas que usen algo que no sea inglés o español, por lo que no sé si no estamos **creando más bien una necesidad** que *actuando* sobre una o un área que admita una mejora.

La funcionalidad de los stacks permite crear etiquetas y usarlas incluso si no se les añade una descripción (que puede ir un poco detrimento del sitio). Algunos tags son autoexplicativos (es lo que se espera de un tag) y existen los medios para crear sinónimos, *re-tagear* preguntas, etc. pero en este caso hay que coger el tag [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) y editarlo con "no usar" o mensaje similar<sup>1</sup>, lo que es otra señal de que probablemente no se necesitan esta familia completa de tags.

Estas etiquetas además pueden exponernos a otros problemas insospechados de manera tangencial (o accidental). En la mayoría de los *stacks* el idioma por defecto es el inglés (por razones obvias). Hasta donde yo sé solo los stacks relacionados con aprender un segundo idioma admiten, valga la redundancia, un segundo idioma (por razones obvias). Un tercer grupo de stacks, los de la familia stackOverflow-enAlgoQueNoEsInlgés, usa un idioma que no es inglés (de nuevo, por razones obvias. De hecho no creo que en Stack Overflow en español admita preguntar en inglés).

En nuestro stack se puede preguntar en español o inglés. Normalmente sugerimos que la respuesta esté en el mismo idioma que la pregunta, pero no es algo que enfatizamos de manera agresiva.Estas etiquetas podrían malinterpretarse como que "damos soporte completo" a [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%c3%b3n) desde cualquier idioma y que una pregunta puede estar en un idioma que no es español o inglés.

Yo seguiría sin diferenciar de ninguna manera estas preguntas en esos idiomas, dado que en las que hemos tenido hasta ahora el saber ese "tercer idioma" (por ejemplo ["¿Cómo se puede traducir el catalán “nostrat” al castellano?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21082/5481)) el saber ese idioma era, si acaso, una **ventaja** y no un **requisito indispensable** para responderla. Si fuese un requisito saber ese idioma nos exponemos además a depender de susuarios que tengan esas habilidades ("Las preguntas con tag [klingon](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) las respondía siempre Spock, que es el único del stack que lo habla, pero lleva tres meses sin dar señales de vida...").

Por tanto no veo beneficio, y anticipo confusión y posible mal uso de estas etiquetas.

---

<sup>1. No basta con no tener el tag, porque entonces, viendo los [alemán](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alem%c3%a1n) , [italiano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italiano), [catalán](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catal%c3%a1n), etc. sería solo cuestión de tiempo que alguien crease [inglés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingl%c3%a9s) y empezase a re-taggear.</sup>

Comment: Debate en curso el [14 de agosto de 2017](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061/2017/8/14) (cómo se notan los días prevacaciones...).