# Would our site like to contribute an opinion to a Meta.SE question about difficulties sites like ours have trying to graduate from Beta?

Tags: discusión, beta, stackexchange

A Meta.SE question [Writing.SE clamours for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/287826) has brought up the difficulties sites like ours have trying to graduate from Beta.

Would we like to weigh in?  Either with one voice, or with multiple voices?

Comment: I'll read it when I can make some time and will post a proper answer. I don't know if we would get much benefit from graduating. Maybe a proper question (for our site) is if we perceive we would get value from graduating and which difficulties we see in doing so. I don't think we should weigh in without discussing those questions here first (which, BTW, wouldn't be much different from our [2018 retrospective](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3015/5481)). To me our main difficulty to graduate is mainly **lack of participation**. Was it your intention to discuss that on this post?

Answer (score 2):

One disadvantage of graduation is that the limits for contributing to the review process are much higher. If we believe, as I do, that it is best to have a wide pool of potential reviewers and not rely too heavily on the diamond mods then graduating would shrink that pool. Disclaimer: it would remove me from at least two of the queues but I suppose I would just have to think of a few more super-interesting questions to gain reputation.

Comment: Interestingly, in Writing.SE's petition they state that "Reputation thresholds for privileges are very very low" and they have users VTCing, editing, etc. "long before they are familiar with the workings of the Stack". Apparently is not difficult to earn reputation there, so low thresholds are a burden for them. I don't think that is the case here (earning rep can be difficult because we don't vote much). I don't think we would loose much "manpower" in the revision queues, but I think it would be **much harder** to earn privileges at the price of a non-beta stack.

Answer (score 1):

**A mediados de 2017**, Spanish.SE estaba experimentando [la mejor racha de crecimiento](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40272427#40272427) de sus 6 años de historia. Más de 15 000 visitas diarias, 100% de preguntas respondidas, más de 500 usuarios "ávidos" (según Area51, claro). La única estadística que teníamos tocada era la de preguntas diarias, pero aún y así estábamos rozando las 5, que según Area51 estaba *okay*.

Frecuentemente se hacían propuestas para hacer el sitio más atractivo, captar usuarios, mejorar la participación, etc. Juegos, recompensas, concursos, "asaltos" a las HNQ, incluso contactos con organismos oficiales y celebridades para darle visibilidad al sitio fuera de la esfera de StackExchange.

Estas iniciativas, no es que estuviesen destinadas a la graduación del sitio, pero el **salir de beta era por entonces un tema recurrente** en el chat y hasta en Meta. Chocaba un poco que, teniendo el doble o el triple de visitas y un ratio similar de preguntas y respuestas que otros stacks ya graduados —Japanese.SE, ejem—, nosotros siguiésemos siendo beta: más allá de que técnicamente no llegásemos a "excelente" en un par de criterios, éramos —y somos— un stack que le daba a StackOverflow mucho más tráfico que otros, y a algunos nos parecía un poco injusto.
Por supuesto, había diversidad de opiniones entre los usuarios más habituales a propósito de si salir de beta nos supondría algún beneficio práctico, más allá de los colorines y el orgullo de conseguirlo; pero ningún usuario lo veía como algo contraproducente.

Con la intención, esta vez sí, de mejorar las estadísticas necesarias para la graduación, llegamos incluso a hacer una [maratón de preguntas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/13628) en octubre de 2017, con [resultados inicialmente excelentes](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2537/13628): **logramos subir la media de preguntas diarias hasta 7** e igualamos el máximo histórico absoluto de preguntas hechas en una sola semana en el sitio: ¡62!

**Este habría sido el momento ideal para hablar con los Community Managers de StackExchange**: con esos datos en la mano, apretar un poco —como están haciendo en Writing.SE—, conseguir por fin la graduación y, con la previsible publicidad del evento, obtener un flujo mayor y más estable de usuarios que nos permitiesen alcanzar los mismos niveles de participación que otros sitios: más preguntas, más respuestas, más votos, menos dependencia de un grupúsculo de usuarios hiperactivos, más usuarios involucrados en Meta...

**¿Sirvió de algo todo lo anterior?**

**No.**

**Faltaba y falta**, en mi opinión, **un ingrediente clave para salir de beta: que el equipo de moderación lo apoyase activamente**. No digo que con eso hubiera bastado para conseguir la graduación, pero sí que sin eso era imposible ya antes siquiera de intentarlo.
En este mismo hilo tienes la opinión de Diego, que no ha variado en estos dos años: se resume en que el sitio está bien como está y no le hace falta salir de beta —su parte de razón tiene, y lo respeto—.
La de fedorqui *creo* que es similar. Puede que él sea un poco menos directo a la hora de expresarla porque, si ve que a los usuarios nos hace ilusión el tema, pues nos anima a proponer cosas y a participar —por eso le tengo tanta estima como moderador—... pero no recuerdo que él personalmente haya dicho "*sí, yo quiero que el sitio salga de beta*".
En cuanto a Flimzy y Joze, los otros dos moderadores, ni están ni se les espera, ni ahora ni entonces —salvo una breve reaparición, precisamente entre finales de 2017 y principios de 2018, causada, me temo, por un [par](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2666/debemos-usar-las-etiquetas-ingl%C3%A9s-o-italiano#comment4382_2666) de [comentarios](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2748/would-moderators-please-be-as-quick-to-reopen-as-they-are-to-close/2749#comment4654_2749) aquí en Meta respecto de su ausencia—; y no parece que les preocupe el devenir del sitio en general. En mi honestísima y humilísima opinión.
Lo que está claro es que, **en un contexto en el que la dirección de SO ya ha dejado claro que lo de [salir de beta está demodé](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), los CM no van a graduar el sitio por iniciativa propia**; la acción positiva del equipo de moderación es condición *sine qua non* para plantearlo siquiera, y en nuestro caso estas condiciones no se daban.

**Pasaron los meses y nada sucedió. Si 2017 fue el mejor año del sitio, 2018 ha sido, de momento, el peor**. El ratio de preguntas diarias volvió a bajar a 5, y después siguió bajando, y bajando... llegando a estar por debajo de 3, en ocasiones. Lo mismo sucedió con los ratios de votos diarios, respuestas... y todo ello a pesar de que teníamos ¡más visitas! que el año anterior.
Sería absurdo negar que el motivo principal de esta caída sostenida en la participación, la primera en 7 años, es que **algunos usuarios dejaron de participar** tan activamente en el sitio. No puedo hablar por otros usuarios, pero sí puedo afirmar que, en mi caso, una de las razones fue no ver ningún tipo de iniciativa por parte de los moderadores para intentar rentabilizar el esfuerzo realizado por la comunidad, así como la aparente indiferencia de ésta hacia tal situación. Tanto moderadores como algunos usuarios han comentado que salir de beta no era ni es importante para ellos, y lo respeto; pero no puedo evitar ver en esta actitud cierto recelo al cambio, cierto deseo de mantener un *statu quo* que, al final, en lo único que va a derivar es en el estancamiento del sitio. Dudo incluso de su viabilidad a medio plazo.

***«Pero muchos otros no se han ido, hay gente nueva, y tú mismo has vuelto.»***
Sí, he vuelto. Me gusta la lingüística, me gustan el español y su historia, me gusta la gente que hay aquí y me gusta sentirme parte de una comunidad que ayuda a otras personas a aprender cosas. Y es cierto que muchos usuarios han seguido aquí dando el callo y que parece que tenemos algunos nuevos que prometen bastante.
Eso no quiere decir que no tenga perspectiva y no sepa distinguir cuándo una comunidad da muestras de hacer aguas, aunque yo decida voluntariamente quedarme tocando en cubierta.
Y en cualquier caso, de cara a la graduación del sitio, que es de lo que estamos hablando, **lo mismo da 500 usuarios activos que 5000: si apenas ninguno de ellos muestra interés por salir de beta** —o por participar en Meta siquiera— y los mods no fomentan activamente el conseguirlo, no hay tutía, al menos en el contexto actual.

---

**Apoyo la iniciativa de Writing.SE**.
Admiro la, en cierto sentido, **valentía de Mónica Cellio**, uno de los moderadores con más experiencia de todo SE, al [cuestionar ante los CM](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/questions-day-and-graduation/1745#1745) la política actual sobre la fase beta y pedir activamente la graduación del sitio, especialmente teniendo en cuenta que ella ya es moderadora de otros sitios ya graduados y que **le sería más que fácil lavarse las manos** en este caso.
Y me gusta ver que la comunidad de Writing.SE en su conjunto se haya planteado esto como objetivo común. **Les deseo toda la suerte del mundo y espero verles graduados pronto**.

En cuanto a Spanish.SE, ese tren ya pasó.

---

<sub>*No voy a negar que esto es, en parte, una crítica. Y no puedo obviar que, como tal crítica, tiene poco de constructiva; es difícil hacer una crítica constructiva cuando se están analizando los motivos de que una oportunidad clave se haya echado a perder. Lo que sí he intentado es exponer mi experiencia personal de una manera neutral, y espero que nadie se lo tome como un ataque, sino como la explicación de por qué creo que en Spanish.SE, ni se dan, ni se van a dar las condiciones necesarias para plantear siquiera el salir de beta.*</sub>

Comment: Caramba, no esperaba tal carga de profundidad pero agradezco mucho que hayas planteado todo esto. Dado que es evidente que los moderadores hemos pasado por alto esta voluntad de la comunidad, sería interesante plantear un debate incluso anterior: ¿nos apetece la graduación? ¿qué beneficios reportaría a la comunidad? Yo estoy encantado de cambiar de opinión, pues con mi posición actual sí es más pro-beta que pro-graduación: creo que la comunidad flojea un poco en su autogestión y los moderadores intervenimos demasiado; graduándonos se acentuaría la tendencia. Hablémoslo. Pueden pasar más trenes

Comment: Y sí, sobre los otros moderadores: técnicamente solo estamos Diego y yo. Costó un montón que se añadiera uno más (sustituyeron a JoulSauron por Diego) y en el proceso de conseguirlo vi que los CM no tenían interés alguno por el sitio. Supongo que allí me resigné un poco.

Comment: Mi respuesta aborda algunos de los puntos tratados en esta, con el añadido de la percibida falta de apoyo de los mods a esta iniciativa. Quiero aclarar que mi respuesta no es una respuesta a la tuya Walen, sino la mía propia (que por supuesto aborda por necesidad los mismos puntos) pero que de paso aclaro lo que yo creo que debe ser la responsabilidad de los moderadores al respecto. Una tercera nota, me queda claro que promueves la graduación del sitio, pero no realmente el porqué. El principal punto de mi oposición es que no veo los beneficios y nadie en sus respuestas los está aclarando.

Comment: "2018 ha sido, de momento, el peor" (y nadie discutió nada al respecto en la [retrospectiva](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3015/5481)). Esta falta de participación en meta puede ser señal de que el sitio no está realmente preparado para graduarse, así como que tras los muchos esfuerzos que enumeras, la media de preguntas diarias alcanzó como max. 7 (se considera que "10 questions per day on average is a **healthy beta**"). Lamento que pienses que no rentabilizamos el esfuerzo para graduar el sitio,  Me hace sentir mal si te has sentido defraudado en ese aspecto pero [continúa abajo]

Comment: [Cont] para mi el objetivo de todo ese esfuerzo es que lo logrado se convirtiese en norma, y no excepción. Es decir, que nunca quise hacer un esfuerzo para graduarnos como objetivo final, sino para mejorar la participación, calidad de los posts, aumentar el número de usuarios con un nivel de reputación decente (y que fuesen activos en tareas de gestión/moderación), etc. que **eventualmente** nos llevaría (cómo no) a graduarnos. Para mi habría sido un fracaso hacer todo eso, graduarnos y luego volver a los "niveles normales" de 2.8 preguntas de media al día, nula participación en meta, etc.

Comment: Repasando lo dicho ayer, así como los comentarios y respuesta de @Diego, creo que no hay que sobrevalorar el peso de los moderadores. Puede parecer que equidistamos entre los CM y los usuarios, pero yo creo que a nivel práctico somos algo así como unos usuarios algo más escuchados. No creo que un argumento potente sea que dos moderadores pidan una graduación, sino más bien unas métricas consistentemente buenas a lo largo de bastantes meses, cosa que creo que en ningún momento hemos podido aportar. Para mí esto incluye tanto preguntas/respuestas como participación en colas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mi opinión muy personal es que nos va muy bien.  Creo que el sitio ofrece un servicio incomparable.   Mucha gente saca beneficio del sitio, por diferentes razones.  A mí me gustaría que se ajustaran las reglas para salir de Beta, o que se creara un tercer renglón de sitios.

---

Why would I personally like to see our site graduate?  I will share some thoughts.

I think that a site that does not strive toward clearly defined goals is at risk of stagnating.  Analogy: an economy that does not get bigger, stagnates.

I think that the activities we would engage in through an effort to reach graduation would be good for the site, in and of themselves.

I'm not sure I was aware of thresholds being different between Beta and Mature.  Hmm. I guess I think that if we find that some of those structures are not working for us, we should request an adjustment.  Analogy: we shouldn't put up with irrational decision making just because "that's what the computer does" -- we should let the programmers know there's a problem, so they can improve the instructions given to the computer, and we should rethink our policies.  Humans should control computers, not the other way around.

I think that graduation, and the work we do to get there, would allow the site to make a quantum leap, qualitatively and quantitatively.  And I think it would help us even things out, for example right now our fearless leaders (moderators) are shouldering a big load.  I think in the long run, our site would be healthier if it were a bit less "top down," with a bit more community moderation.  (Not that I'm an anarchist.  I do think it's important to have strong moderators to take things to when necessary.)

The goal of graduating is a goal I'm comfortable working towards.  However, I'm open to a collaboration to define an alternate goal.  (I wouldn't be comfortable with static coasting and no shared goals.)

Comment: Coincido con que al sitio le va bien. Por eso yo no veo necesidad real en salir de beta. Podrías por favor ampliar un poco la respuesta añadiendo qué tendríamos si saliésemos de beta o qué querríamos tener en ese "tercer renglón"? Gracias.

Comment: Los mods no somos "líderes". Somos usuarios bastante activos y tiramos un poco del carro (al igual que otros usuarios). Predicamos con el ejemplo, pero el puesto de mods no nos hace "líderes". No sé hasta que punto podemos pedir que nos ajusten a nuestro capricho los límites de privilegios. Como fedorqui ya ha explicado, muchas de las peticiones, especialmente en lo referente a infraestructura, tardan mucho en atenderse si es que acaso llegan a atenderse. Sigo pensando que no es la graduación en sí lo que traería mejoras, sino los pasos para conseguir la graduación. Son dos cosas distintas.

Comment: @Diego - I'm not sure we are on opposite sides of an issue or debate.  For example, "no es la graduación en sí lo que traería mejoras, sino los pasos para conseguir la graduación" is, I think, another way of stating what I was trying to get across. // I'm confused.  Did I say or imply that the moderators were *líderes*?  I didn't mean to.  Let me try to clarify.  My understanding is that as a Beta site works towards graduation, the community takes on more and more of the moderation, via community moderation.  I'm saying that that is one of the positives that come with striving for graduation.

Comment: Thank you. I posted that comment precisely because it is getting confusing in the debate _how_ we want to achieve graduation. I don't think that are any voices against graduation or against working to get more/better questions, answers, stats, etc. But the example of WritingSE is to request that the site gets graduated, in spite of not meeting the established criteria. They claim they are above a certain threshold and that that should be fine for them. I feel that is an aspect of the debate that seems not to be clear enough.

Comment: @Diego - Not sure if I understand your comment (question?) but I will say that I personally think we are not ready for graduation yet, and I also think that unless the required components can be tweaked I don't see how we can ever make it.  Which I find discouraging.  The measure I feel pessimistic about is the # of questions per day. // The reason I personally think we're not ready yet is that I think we need to start transitioning toward a greater degree of community moderation (I'm using "moderation" in a very broad sense) first.  I don't know exactly how that can be promoted, though.

Comment: aparente001 agreed with your last bit _we need to start transitioning toward a greater degree of community moderation_. We need more people to go through the `/review` section. Otherwise it is @Diego and me cleaning it up, which works in the meanwhile but just hides the underlying problem. We decided some time ago to not check it so often, but to me items in the review queue still take too long to be solved by the community (quite often it takes few days) and we tend to end up doing something in there.

Comment: @fedorqui - I see.  I will post a Meta question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Mi opinión sobre *forzar* la salida del stack de beta es la siguiente:

## No lo apoyo porque no están claras las condiciones en las que haríamos dicha salida (y por tanto sus consecuencias y beneficios).

Para empezar, cuestiono los beneficios que nos daría no ser un sito beta (sin lograr los requisitos para graduarnos por nuestra propia cuenta). **Qué tiene el sitio graduado que no tenemos en beta y que nos hace falta?** Para continuar, siempre que oigo el tema de forzar o promover la salida de beta, sería o bien para pasar directamente a sitio graduado, o para pasar (si fuese posible, que no es nada claro) a un sitio intermedio entre beta y sitio graduado (con lo que la reputación que se necesitaría para cada [privilegio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), junto con los servicios que dicho sitio tendría, son un misterio).

Yo  creo que lo que falta es principalmente **mayor participación** y que esa participación se mantenga de manera consistente de forma natural (en contraposición a mantenerla de forma artificial todo el tiempo mediante iniciativas similares al maratón de preguntas) y en segundo lugar (y directamente relacionado con lo primero) **menor dependencia de un cierto grupo de usuarios**.

Walen lista en [su respuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3027/5481) un montón de iniciativas que no han terminado de fructificar. En mi lista estaría el [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf), donde siempre terminaban participando los mismos y que cayó en el olvido o las [mejores preguntas del trimestre](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916/5481), donde también participaban siempre los mismos, que revisitamos para premiar a usuarios nuevos faltos de reputación (en lugar al grupo del "núcleo duro" de siempre) y que también cayó en el olvido (yo siempre lo atribuí a falta de interés). Estos serían ejemplos de que hay ciertas actitudes e iniciativas que no podemos mantener de forma continuada de manera artificial y forzada. Lo mismo con varios recordatorios/intentos para que votásemos más, involucrásemos más a los usuarios, etc. El que algunas de estas cosas no terminen de calar, me dice que la comunidad (más allá del mencionado grupo de usuarios superactivos) no está del todo preparada, y pasar a sitio graduado, no necesariamente cambiará esto.

Clarifico que nuestra dependencia de este grupo de usuarios no es solo para aportar respuestas de gran calidad, sino también para aportar preguntas (y que el sitio no esté incluso "más muerto" de lo habitual). No es sorprendente que estos usuarios sean a los que se ve con más frecuencia en [las colas de revisión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review).

Igualmente con la participación en Meta. Esta pregunta está teniendo una acogida excepcional, pero hace poco publicamos una [retrospectiva de 2018](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3015/5481) y no hubo tanta participación, al igual que con otras preguntas de meta. Me llama la atención que parece ser que discutimos sobre mejorar el sitio en sí cuando hablamos de salir de beta, pero no necesariamente para mejorar el sitio por mejorar el sitio, que es una actividad que deberíamos estar haciendo **continuamente**, y que es esencial sobre todo en un sitio graduado.

Con esto quiero decir que parece ser que hay **más ganas que necesidad real** de salir de beta. Entiendo y no desapruebo esta actitud. Entiendo que es muy fácil ver o proponerse la graduación del sitio como una meta a la que aspirar, pero entiendo que ese objetivo final debería ser lo que nos lleve a promover cambios que nos acerquen al objetivo. Coger el atajo (pedir a los *Communit Managers* que gradúen el sitio por las buenas) no nos garantiza que obtendremos todas las cosas necesarias y deseables que un sitio graduado tiene (básicamente, **una comunidad sólida**).

Resumiendo:

- No tengo claros qué beneficios tendríamos como sitio graduado que no tengamos ya.
- Como las condiciones de la "graduación" no están claras, me da miedo que los usuarios pierdan privilegios (seguramente no perderíamos mucho, pero creo que durante algún tiempo podríamos ver unas colas de revisión más saturadas).
- Entiendo las ganas de salir de beta, pero si no conseguimos aumentar la participación, el sitio no va a cambiar absolutamente nada por no llamarlo "beta" (más allá de ciertas condiciones cosméticas como tener logo propio, distinto *look and feel* y distinta [relación reputación/privilegios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges))

Yo veo la graduación del sitio como un medio, **no como un objetivo**. Quizá no sea ni eso, y sea solo un reconocimiento de que el sitio ha alcanzado cierta masa crítica. Y cualquier cosa que se consiga (más y mejores preguntas y respuestas, más revisiones y votos en los posts...) hay que **mantenerlo** a lo largo del tiempo.

---

Un último apunte sobre la falta de apoyo de los moderadores en general, o mía en particular, a la hora de apoyar que el sitio salga de beta. Los moderadores tenemos acceso a funcionalidad que el resto de usuarios no tienen para realizar las tareas de moderación, pero **a efectos de participación, somos usuarios normales**. Nuestro voto cuenta lo mismo que el de cualquier otro usuario y en el pasado los moderadores en general, y yo mismo en particular, hemos aceptado decisiones con las que no estábamos de acuerdo simplemente porque se habían votado en Meta y la comunidad las había apoyado/aprobado (Uno de los primeros ejemplos que me vienen a la cabeza es precisamente una de las [preguntas enlazadas por Walen](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2666/5481))

Los moderadores no tenemos opinión como moderadores, sino como usuarios. Al ser moderadores tratamos de participar más en meta y podemos aportar una perspectiva con las experiencia recogida al hacer las tareas de moderación, pero eso no es más que la opinión de un usuario cualquiera.

Yo, como usuario, puedo estar en contra de intentar forzar la graduación del sitio. Si la voluntad de la comunidad es a favor, y se necesita que los moderadores hagan cierta tarea, por supuesto la haré/haremos, aunque piense que no es la mejor idea. No creo haber visto iniciativas o propuestas bien decididas y recibidas destinadas a graduar el sitio, o por lo menos que tuviesen o necesitasen claros "*action items*" por parte de los moderadores (realizar alguna tarea, o servir de *proxy/portavoz* de la comunidad en conversaciones con los "*Community Managers*" por ejemplo). Hasta ahora, no creo haber visto por parte de la comunidad peticiones claras de los moderadores hagamos XYZ en ese sentido. El que nosotros los moderadores hagamos algo a petición de la comunidad y el que hagamos algo por iniciativa propia, que se alinee más o menos con la voluntad de la comunidad, son dos cosas distintas.

Yo como moderador trabajaré en las tareas que se identifiquen necesarias por parte del equipo de moderadores para la graduación del sitio si la comunidad lo pide, incluso si, como usuario, no creo que sea la mejor idea o lo que la comunidad realmente necesite.

Comment: Es interesante destacar que nuestra interacción con Stack Exchange como compañía es bastante limitada: te envían un email tipo sugiriéndote ser moderador y tienes una semana para decir sí o no. De repente te encuentras con un diamante detrás de tu nombre de usuario y cero información de qué hacer y cómo. Con suerte otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otro) te irán descubriendo cosas, alguna página de ayuda y un chat privado para todos los moderadores, donde suele haber algún CM. El ambiente en ese chat es distendido y se tratan muchos temas, pero normalmente son de sitios grandes.

Comment: Yo he participado en algunos momentos para pedir consejo para alguna situación de Spanish.SE y han sido otros moderadores los que han dado opiniones. También contacté directamente con los CM en un par de casos y la respuesta tardó bastante en llegar y, por ello, tuve la sensación de que un sitio pequeño, además en un idioma que casi ningún CM entiende, estaba muy abajo en su lista de prioridades y que otros sitios Beta bastante más grandes tampoco despertaban demasiado interés.

Comment: Hay pocos CM (el número ha bajado en el último año), la compañía se centra en SO Teams y las iniciativas sobre sitios Beta apenas llegan a buen puerto, por lo que yo hace cierto tiempo que veo que o se llega con unos números estratosféricos, o poco se puede hacer. ¡Si incluso SOes, con más de cien preguntas diarias, tarda siglos en que le solucionen los bugs! ([ejemplo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268826/209901)).