# ¿Qué implicaciones tiene graduarse?

Tags: discusión, faq, beta

Al hilo de la pregunta [Would our site like to contribute an opinion to a Meta.SE question about difficulties sites like ours have trying to graduate from Beta?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3024/1674) ha resurgido el debate sobre qué tan interesante sería que el sitio se graduara.

Para centrar el debate, creo que sería interesante que listáramos aquí todas las consecuencias que tendría una graduación.

Dejo una respuesta Wiki para que añadamos los elementos objetivos de tal paso.

Comment: Buena iniciativa. Creo que además de listar las los **cambios** que traería la graduación, en respuestas individuales cada usuario podría interpretar **cómo nos afectarían** y lo deseables que serían. Por ejemplo, queda claro que el coste de privilegios cambiarían. Para WritingSE es algo deseable, porque hay gente no del todo preparada haciendo uso de ellos (debe ser más fácil ganar rep ahí). En cambio, nosotros seguramente perderíamos gente capaz de participar en las revisiones. Puede además haber más cambios que los que trae la graduación en sí, como una distinta percepción del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

**Cambios oficiales**:

- Nuevos límites para los **privilegios**.

[image]

- **Elecciones** a moderador.
- **Diseño propio** en el sitio.
- Capacidad de la comunidad de **migrar preguntas** a otros sitios también graduados.

  - Y su recíproco: capacidad de **aparecer como destino de migración** en otros sitios graduados.
- Aparecer **listado** en la parte inferior de la página.

---

**Alternativas** a lo anterior existentes **para los sitios Beta**:

- **Elecciones**: hay un proyecto en marcha para hacer [elecciones a moderador *pro tempore* en sitios Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/209901). El procedimiento no es exactamente el mismo:

  - Solo se hacen si el actual equipo de moderación quiere:

    > We're reaching out to moderator teams to see if they would be interested in participating.
  - Los moderadores actuales mantienen su cargo sin necesidad de presentarse a dicha elección, a menos que ellos mismos pidan ser reemplazados:

    > Current moderators will not be required to nominate themselves—they will continue as moderators unless they ask to step down.
  - Si se presentaren pocos candidatos, ni siquiera habría votación — se les nombraría automáticamente:

    > If the number of nominees is less than or equal to the number of open slots, we'll end the election before the voting stage.
- **Migrar preguntas**: los moderadores pueden migrar una pregunta al *stack* que consideren más adecuado, en base al *feedback* de la comunidad.

---

**Cosas que antes requerían de graduación**:

- **Crear un blog**: [actualmente los blogs ya no se mantienen ni se pueden crear nuevos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741/209901).
- **Tener anuncios de la comunidad**: según [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248216/362105), en realidad nunca hubo una regla que prohibiese a los sitios Beta tener estos anuncios.
  Lo que pasa es que antes de ponerlos preguntan en el Meta del sitio, y solo los ponen si obtienen una respuesta "abrumadoramente positiva" de la comunidad, cosa que en los sitios Beta no suele suceder, según el autor (¿CM?) de esa misma respuesta:

  > If the response is overwhelmingly positive, then Stack Exchange will set up the necessary systems to make it happen on your site. Most beta sites, though, don't have a community large or interested enough for these ads to be worthwhile or useful.

---

**Enlaces interesantes** de donde sacar info (cuidado que hay cosas desfasadas):

- [¿Qué cambia cuando el sitio pasa de beta a graduado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1810/83)
- [What is the Stack Exchange (Staff) process of launching a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199551/209901)
- [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/209901)
- [Feedback Requested: Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation)
- [How do we get Community Promotion Ads on beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites)
- [When Will My Site Graduate?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Comment: ... trabajo en progreso .... añadid las cosas que vayáis encontrando

Answer (score 0):

Puesto que fedorqui ha indicado que la respuesta wiki es para los elementos objetivos, presento aquí los...

### Elementos no objetivos

#### Cambios en el crecimiento del sitio

La mayoría de sitios analizados en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257716/362105) experimentaron un crecimiento mayor tras su graduación.
No está claro que la graduación sea la causa de ese mayor crecimiento (en los comentarios de esa respuesta se puede encontrar un abanico de interpretaciones), pero ahí están los datos para quien los quiera analizar.
Algunos otros que he sacado por mi cuenta (nótese que Spanish.SE lleva en Beta desde 2011):

- [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/): graduado en 2012 con [ratios similares y menos usuarios y tráfico](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles) que nosotros. [Gráfica](https://data.stackexchange.com/bicycles/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=1000#graph).
- [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/): graduado en 2013 con [peores ratios](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity) que nosotros. [Gráfica](https://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=1000#graph).
- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/): graduado en 2012 con [ratios similares y menos usuarios y tráfico](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing) que nosotros. [Gráfica](https://data.stackexchange.com/photo/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=1000#graph).
- [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/): graduado en 2012 con [peores ratios](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) que nosotros. [Gráfica](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=1000#graph).

De nuevo, nadie dice que el crecimiento o decrecimiento de cada sitio esté causado por su graduación. Ahí están las fechas y las gráficas, que cada cual se forme su opinión.

Por otra parte, la posibilidad de convertirnos en destino de migración de otros sitios graduados, podría suponer también una vía de llegada de nuevos usuarios y nuevas preguntas desde sitios como ELL o ELU que, a día de hoy, quizá simplemente cierren esas preguntas como off-topic para no complicarse mucho (como hacemos a veces aquí con las preguntas sobre cómo expresar en inglés un concepto en español — técnicamente es una pregunta para ELU pero no siempre las migramos).

#### Cambios en la base de usuarios con privilegios

Se puede dividir en tres frentes:

- **Pérdida de privilegios de los usuarios**: todos salvo Charlie perderemos algún privilegio con los nuevos niveles. Esto no debería ser un problema para los usuarios activos, dado que los recuperarán más pronto que tarde. Para el resto, que cada cual considere si es bueno o malo que usuarios con poca participación en el sitio tengan pocos privilegios.
- **Efectos de tener menos usuarios con privilegios**: en mi opinión, ninguno negativo. ¿500 puntos en vez de 350 para acceder a las colas? ¿2000 en vez de 1000 para poder editar sin pasar por revisión? ¿3000 en vez de 500 para poder votar por el cierre de una pregunta sin usar flags? No veo el problema.
- **Mayor reputación requerida para alcanzar algunos privilegios**: esto en todo caso lo que conseguirá es que los usuarios se esfuercen más y durante más tiempo (que se piquen más, vaya) para conseguir los privilegios. Es la base de toda la *gamificación* que usa Stack Exchange para fidelizar a los usuarios, no veo de qué manera puede suponer un problema.

#### Cambios en la moderación

La graduación del sitio conllevará la convocatoria inmediata de elecciones a moderador.
Estas elecciones serían completas (las diferencias con las elecciones *pro tempore* están explicadas en la respuesta CW). Actualmente tenemos cuatro moderadores, luego entiendo que se abrirían cuatro vacantes (quizá alguna más, quizá alguna menos... no creo que sea relevante para lo que comento a continuación).

Este cambio puede ser bueno o malo dependiendo de quién salga elegido, obviamente. Se comprendería que Diego o fedorqui sientan cierta intranquilidad ante la posibilidad de que salga elegido alguien con ideas contrarias, o que no trabaje bien en equipo, o que tenga poca experiencia y meta la pata cada dos por tres. Al fin y al cabo todo depende de quién se presente y de lo que vote la comunidad, que a saber.
Pero bueno, al menos habría un equipo de moderadores al 100% en vez de al 50%.

Y sí, estoy dando por hecho que tanto Diego como fedorqui se presentarían a dichas elecciones y saldrían elegidos, no creo que eso sea motivo de debate.

Comment: Sobre lo de _La mayoría de sitios analizados en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257716/362105) experimentaron un crecimiento mayor tras su graduación_ es bueno analizar los comentarios que tiene, pues se pone en duda que haya relación de causalidad. Ya lo comentas en la respuesta, pero creo que es bueno tenerlo en cuenta porque no hay dato objetivo que lo respalde, más allá de pequeñas mejoras en el gráfico.

Comment: En lo de _Mayor reputación requerida para alcanzar algunos privilegios_ estoy de acuerdo que puede servir de acicate para que la gente se lance a conseguir más puntos.

Comment: Sobre las elecciones: no tiene porqué ser de cuatro moderadores. [es.so] se graduó y convocó elecciones con tres plazas. Nosotros tenemos (excepcionalmente) cuatro moderadores pues se han ido añadiendo a medida que algunos estaban más ausentes. Muchos sitios tienen menos (véase la [lista de todos los moderadores](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators)).