# Desaparecería este stack de no haber moderadores disponibles?

Tags: discusión

En [2020 Moderator Elections — Community Interest Check / ¿Alguien interesado en presentarse?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3313/5481) comenta el actual moderador que

> [...] prefiero que el sitio siga adelante con un moderador [...] a que **sea borrado por falta de moderadores**.

Y no es la única persona a la que se lo he oído (o leído). No sé si esto ha sido discutido o explicado en [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) u otro sitio.

Revisando la secuencia de eventos en [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/356575) veo que por lo menos [Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/the-moderators-of-blender-stack-exchange-are-on-strike) se quedó sin moderadores *activos*. Viendo [sus perfiles](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) entiendo que simplemente están o en su momento estuvieron todos inactivos al mismo tiempo, pero oficialmente el sitio tiene (y siempre ha tenido) tres moderadores. Prácticamente lo mismo aplica para [Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/), que en su momento no tuvo moderadores activos. No he podido encontrar ejemplos de stacks que hayan perdido todos los moderadores y donde no hubiese nuevos candidatos para el cargo.

¿Tenemos alguna evidencia de qué pasaría si el stack se quedase sin moderadores? 
¿Sería moderado por los *Community Managers* o en verdad se arriesgaría ser borrado, o al menos puesto en "cuarentena"?

Comment: En Italian.SE tuvimos un momento hace años en que costó un poco encontrar un moderador que faltaba (y no eran elecciones). Y recibimos este comentario de Robert Cartaino:  "I was getting worried since a lack of folks willing to step up to moderate is just about the only thing that can [get a site shut down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)". Era un momento en que teníamos dos moderadores activos, pero faltaba un tercero.

Comment: Interesante (**Muy interesante**), porque ahí no se dice "si no encontramos **al menos un moderador** (más)", sino que es la "falta de voluntarios en las elecciones" lo que hace cerrar el sitio. Ahora me pregunto si el sitio podría cerrarse igual, incluso aunque Charlie siguiese como mod, de no haber candidatos en las elecciones. Pero entonces estabais en beta en Italian.SE, no?

Comment: Cito del artículo enlazado: If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Code of Conduct to be upheld, your site will remain open. However, if community leaders drop off, flags sit without being addressed, and we can’t find any suitable volunteers to step forward, the site gets closed.

Comment: Sí, y todavía lo estamos.

Comment: Qué buena la info, @Charo. Veo que todo pasó en [Additional Pro Tem Needed — Who would like to Moderate this site?](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1256/2505).

Comment: Sí, @fedorqui'SOstopharming': viene de allí.

Comment: El tema Beta/no beta no creo que tenga demasiada relevancia en nuestro caso. Salimos del beta pero solo a efectos de título, el resto de cosas siguen iguales: límites para reputación, diseño, migraciones, etc (véase [¿Qué implicaciones tiene graduarse?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3030/1674) sobre qué pensábamos que cambiaría).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Te doy la razón. No es que ninguna de [nuestras estadísticas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3293/5481) sea buena en cualquier caso, pero entiendo que el coste de la infraestructura para mantener el sitio (servidores, bases de datos y demás) es irrisorio comparado con lo que costaría pagar a un humano para moderar. De ahí que necesiten voluntarios para hacerlo gratis. De tener que dedicar recursos humanos de SE a moderar (como usar tiempo de los CM) incrementaría el "coste" del stack, este sería menos rentable y entonces pasado cierto umbral... ZAS!

Comment: Sí, sí, absolutamente de acuerdo en lo que planteas. No me consta ningún sitio que haya sido cerrado por este motivo e incluso Spanish.SE tuvo un tiempo en que los flags caducaban por no haber moderadores activos. SE es bastante robusto en cuanto a que puede ir bastante solo, sobre todo ahora que hay herramientas paralelas de detección de spam y flags automáticos. En cualquier caso, no es deseable llegar a ese extremo porque como bien dices las horas de CM deben ser bastante caras (y más ahora que hay tan pocos)

Comment: Mi experiencia es que hay flags, spam y, muy muy muy de vez en cuando (al menos en Italian.SE), cosas más graves que gestionar que requiren personas que sigan de cerca el comportamiento del sitio (y usar una lengua que no es el inglés creo que a veces complicaría demasiado una hipotética gestión por parte de un CM).

Comment: @Charo sí, todos los aquí presentes somos o hemos sido moderadores. Dicho lo cual, el CM JNat lee con solvencia el castellano y también está Juan M que es medio mexicano

Comment: Sí, lo sé, @fedorqui, y supongo que el español tiene esta ventaja respecto otras lenguas con menos hablantes. Simplemente intentaba hacer la reflexión sobre si los CM aceptarían hacerse cargo directamente de ciertas cosas, pero quizás sí, no sé.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [this post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/208518), which addresses your question directly:

> Thanks to many devoted users, it’s grown clear that smaller SE sites can do a great job of maintaining themselves and producing high quality Q&A. Not every site is going to be a blockbuster success, but our small sites are serving their own communities well. We’re proud of you, and we want you here.
>
> What does this mean? **If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Code of Conduct to be upheld, your site will remain open.** However, if community leaders drop off, flags sit without being addressed, and we can’t find any suitable volunteers to step forward, the site gets closed.

This doesn't mean that a failed election automatically results in site closure: we'll at least give the site a second chance at an election (around a month or so after the first election failed, possibly), and do the best to convey the urgency that the second election does not fail — hopefully that'll mean more people will step up. But if that fails, and the site is left with no moderators while flags pile up... welp, see above :\