# Announcing an upcoming election

Tags: discusión, elecciones

**Summary**: Spanish Language Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **October 5**, [as your "graduation" election](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3313/8740).

The timeline:

- On September 28, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on October 5, users can [nominate themselves](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- On October 12, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. If at the end of this extension period there are still not four or more candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 20 (or on the 27th, if we need to extend the nomination period and only get 4 or more candidates then).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: There was this question a while ago that is still unanswered, could a CM take a look at it? [Desaparecería este stack de no haber moderadores disponibles?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3317/1674)

Comment: @Jnat, out of curiosity, could that question be answered, please? What happens to a stack that for some reason has no mods?Is it moderated by CMs?

Comment: I've answered the question, @Diego; apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that we get the proper number of candidates, one concern we have is that the participation in Meta is quite low on this site. So is there a minimum number of voters required for the election to be valid?

Comment: There isn't, no. But, regardless of how engaged your community is on Meta, every user who has enough rep to be able to nominate, and then to vote, will get inbox notifications at the appropriate election phase.