# ¿Sobre qué elementos de revisión debemos evitar los mods ejercer el "binding vote"?

Tags: discusión, moderación

Los moderadores tenemos un ["binding vote" para todos los elementos del stack que moderamos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300783/356575) (cerrar y abrir preguntas, borrar y desborrar contribuciones - cualquier cosa en las colas de revisión). Esto significa que se necesitan 5 votos de usuarios para reabrir o cerrar una pregunta, pero un único voto de un moderador.

Desde ya hace tiempo, los moderadores hemos intentado no ejercer el "binding vote" sobre las colas de revisión para cerrar o reabrir preguntas (intervenimos solo en casos muy claros o para dar el quinto y último voto de cierre, o quizá el tercero, en casos que sean claros y estén tomando algo más de tiempo de lo normal).

Sobre contribuciones "low quality post" y "not an answer", de manera habitual usamos alguno de los recursos de la [lista de comentarios útiles para el sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2622/5481) para dar la bienvenida a un usuario nuevo e inexperto a la par que explicamos un problema en su contribución y ofrecemos posibles soluciones.

En bastantes casos estas contribuciones de baja calidad o que no responden realmente a la pregunta vienen de usuarios no registrados, que no suelen volver y editar/mejorar el contenido de sus contribuciones. Yo tiendo a tomar alguna acción  cuando las veo (borrar, mover a comentario) en lugar de esperar a que el usuario las modifique.

De igual manera que con los votos de cierre o reapertura, algunas de estas contribuciones a veces ya tienen votos para ser eliminadas, o han sido votadas como "low quality" o "not an answer" por otros usuarios. Si embargo, como moderador, mi voto en las colas de revisión realiza la acción en lugar a esperar tener consenso, y hay quien me ha hecho notar que en los casos de "low quality answers" y "not an answer" debería ser también la comunidad la que decidiese sobre estas contribuciones, sin intervenciones de "votos de decisión unilaterales" o "votos decisivos", para no imponer el criterio de una persona, aunque sea moderador.

Por tanto, pregunto a la comunidad (especialmente porque [estamos intentando atraer más actividad a las colas de revisión](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3032/5481)) ¿Sobre qué elementos de revisión debemos evitar los moderadores ejercer nuestro "binding vote"?

Answer (score 2):

Una comunidad necesita de la existencia de objetivos y tareas comunes para sentirse como tal. Si un miembro de una comunidad no tiene nada que hacer en común con otros miembros, no puede sentirse parte de esa comunidad.

Los privilegios de Stack Exchange están pensados en parte para que los usuarios vayan adquiriendo poco a poco un sentimiento de pertenencia a la comunidad, al ir obteniendo acceso a nuevas tareas de moderación en las que colaborar con el resto de miembros; privilegios que obtienen como premio a su participación activa en el sitio y que les distingue como usuarios con mayor experiencia.
Esta simple distinción es muchas veces suficiente para que un usuario se sienta más responsable del devenir del sitio en general, y busque activamente participar más y mejor en la moderación del mismo.

Una de esas tareas de moderación que ayudan a establecer un sentimiento de comunidad es atender las colas de revisión.
Se requieren 5 votos de la comunidad en un mismo sentido para llevar a cabo acciones determinantes (como el cierre, borrado o reapertura), lo cual propicia el debate entre los usuarios revisores y la participación democrática en pos de un objetivo común: limpiar las colas de revisión.
Por si eso no fuera suficiente, se otorgan [distinciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges/78/reviewer) específicas por llevar a cabo esta tarea de manera continuada, lo cual redunda en lo dicho anteriormente.

Cuando un moderador participa de estas tareas, suceden dos cosas:

1. que se le hurta a otro usuario la oportunidad de participar en esa tarea común; y
2. que está impidiendo que se den esos debates y esa actividad democrática de la comunidad que mencionaba antes.

Esto es así porque, lo quiera o no (y me consta que muchas veces es a su pesar), el voto de un moderador es un [voto de oro](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28831/13628) que pone fin al proceso de revisión inmediatamente: una vez emitido, nadie más puede votar; nadie más puede participar.

Ahora, echemos un vistazo al histórico de revisiones de [algunas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) [de las](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/history) [colas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history), o incluso a la lista de usuarios que tienen alguna de las chapas de revisión que requieren una actividad continuada (como la enlazada más arriba).
Salta a la vista que la mitad o más de las revisiones las llevan a cabo los moderadores, con el efecto ya comentado: que, aunque sea involuntariamente, se evita la participación del resto de la comunidad en esta tarea.

Y me pregunto: ¿es necesario?

Podría argumentarse que los moderadores se ven forzados a actuar sobre las colas de revisión porque sienten que la comunidad no participa lo suficiente en esta tarea. Dicho de otra manera: "lo hago yo porque, si no, nadie lo hace".
¿Y si en realidad fuera al revés?
¿Y si el problema es que "nadie lo hace porque ya lo hago yo"?

Desde luego, por falta de afluencia de usuarios no es: se puede observar que varios de los usuarios no moderadores que participan en las colas, lo hacen a diario o cada pocos días. El problema es que más de la mitad de revisiones son despachadas por un moderador, y por tanto no queda nada más que revisar.
¿Cuántos usuarios se han quedado sin participar en alguna revisión porque un voto de oro le ha puesto fin cuando solo habían participado uno o dos usuarios? ¿Cuántos usuarios pueden haberse cansado de entrar a revisar las colas porque, cuando lo hacen, nunca queda nada que revisar? ¿Cuántos usuarios se han cansado de intentar obtener esas distinciones que les presentarían como revisores activos ante la comunidad y que podrían haber reforzado su sentido de pertenencia a la misma?

Los moderadores, además de las colas de revisión, tienen otras tareas que solo ellos pueden llevar a cabo: revisión de la *mod queue*, atender peticiones en Meta, limpieza de tags, e imagino que varias más.

Así que reitero: **¿es necesario que los moderadores participen en las colas de revisión?**

En mi opinión: **no**. Los moderadores deberían dejar que sea la comunidad la que se encargue de las colas de revisión (de todas). Confiar en que hay usuarios suficientes que quieren participar en las mismas; aceptar que hacerlo así implicará que algunos elementos pasen algo más de tiempo en cola, y ver esto como un incentivo para la participación de los usuarios, en vez de como un problema.

Solo en caso de necesidad, cuando algún usuario pida su intervención para desbloquear un debate, o para corregir situaciones en las que, en su criterio de moderador (siempre válido), el comportamiento colectivo de la comunidad haya sido injusto o contrario al [Código de Conducta](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct); solo bajo esos términos, es cuando un moderador debería hacer uso de su voto de oro. Para eso está, que no es poco, y para eso debería usarse; ni más, ni, por supuesto, menos.

En mi humilde opinión.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Tal vez esto sea incluso una posible solución a la ya mencionada [How can we encourage participants to assist with the “review” queue?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3032/5481). Yo por mi parte me voy a contener un poco de participar en las reviews, y ya veremos cómo la comunidad valida esta respuesta (o si aporta otras distintas). Un par de apuntes: No es que el voto de oro no se pueda deshacer (si me equivoco al cerrar una pregunta con mi voto de oro, se puede reabrir, desborrar un post, etc.) pero entiendo el punto que aportas sobre q desmotiva la participación.

Comment: Aparte, en caso de que sea la voluntad de la comunidad que los mods participemos lo menos posible ne esos procesos, la comunidad debe tener en cuenta que la **percepción** va a ser que los mods están ausentes,o que participan como usuarios normales en preguntas/respuestas (ya que las otras cosas que hacemos los mods no son del todo visibles a la comunidad). Lo menciono porque ya  alguna vez se ha discutido que no todos los mods parecen estar muy activos, y podría parecer que pasamos a tener a los 4 mods poco activos en tareas de moderación. Habrá que ser coherente y consciente con la decisión.

Comment: Para terminar: no es que los mods nos carguemos de trabajo porque no confiemos en la comunidad o veamos que las cosas no se hacen o tarden demasiado. Simplemente somos usuarios muy activos en varios niveles (que es una de las razones por las que los CM nos ofrecieron a cada uno el puesto de moderadores). Lo que planteas tiene sentido, pero podría ser como pedirle a los usuarios más activos que no respondan tantas preguntas para que otros tengan la oportunidad de hacerlo y ganen rep. Una cosa es que los mods nos apartemos de las colas un tiempo para un fin determinado y otra permanentemente

Comment: Es importante destacar que la _mod queue_ no es una cola independiente de la de las revisiones: en muchos casos (_low quality_, _late answers_...) entran a la vez en las colas de revisión generales y en la de flags de los moderadores.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con esta respuesta. El voto de oro debería ser para casos flagrantes de preguntas o respuestas que violen el código de conducta, como casos claros de spam, faltas de respeto, etc. Para todo lo demás, mast... digo, que la comunidad decida.