# ¿Hay más colas de revisión con "problemas" aparte de las cierre / reapertura?

Tags: discusión, colas-de-revisión

A fecha de hoy tengo varios *flags* todavía pendientes de resolver. El más antiguo parece que es del 3 de diciembre (más de 10 días).

Entiendo que los elementos de las colas se resuelven al ritmo que se resuelven, pero, mientras esperamos a que finalmente nos hagan ese ajuste para [cambiar el número necesario de votos para cerrar o reabrir preguntas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3260/5481) y podamos [valorar de nuevo cómo va la resolución de elementos de estas colas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4407/5481), quería preguntar si hay alguna otra de nuestras colas de revisión donde hayamos identificado que los elementos no se resuelven a un ritmo que consideremos prudente.

Entiendo que hay cierta percepción subjetiva en lo que debe ser el tiempo "aceptable" para resolver un flag. En las colas de cierre o reapertura el interés es dar feedback temprano a los usuarios para que puedan mejorar preguntas que no se ajustan a los estándares del sitio. Me pregunto si hay un problema parecido con las *low quality* / *not an answer* u otras colas donde podamos ayudar a los usuarios nuevos a mejorar sus contribuciones.

Comment: Buena pregunta. Antes debería definirse qué es "problema". Para los [pocos] usuarios que revisamos, es que algo se enquiste, así como que apenas haya media docena de usuarios mirándolo. Por tanto, la mirada está algo viciada. Para la comunidad en general, que su utilidad sea poca. Muchas respuestas cortas vienen de usuarios sin registrar que rara vez vuelven, por lo que los comentarios que les podamos hacer difícilmente los llegarán a ver. A mí me parece que una mejora grande sería poder agilizar la conversión a comentarios o [juntarlas como CW](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Sí, ese es el caso que me encuentro con más frecuencia, y suelo dejar el comentario más por la comunidad o por mero trámite que por el _unregistered user_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente, la cola *[Low Quality Posts](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history)* tiene cierto retraso. Ahora mismo, hay 6 publicaciones en esa cola, y la más antigua es del 3 de diciembre. A esta cola llegan las publicaciones que tienen algún flag "not an answer"/"very low quality" (tengo entendido que esas dos *flags* tienen el mismo efecto).

El borrado de respuestas requiere solo tres votos, pero estos votos tienen que venir de usuarios con más de 4000 puntos de reputación<sup>1</sup>, de los cuales no hay muchos activos. Sospecho que la razón del retraso es que muchas de las publicaciones que llegan a esa cola están un poco en la frontera entre lo que merece ser borrado y lo que no. Muchas [sí que son respuestas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37168/24236), pero son cortas y no incluyen referencias (o no incluyen información nueva con respecto a otras respuestas). Parece ser (aunque no estoy seguro) que algunos miembros de la comunidad no están seguros de qué hacer con esas respuestas, y por tanto no aplican ninguna acción. Además, algunas de esas respuestas tienen incluso votos positivos, lo cual hace que no se puedan borrar con tres votos.

Si esta es la razón (que repito que no estoy seguro), me gustaría pedir a la comunidad que *[se moje](https://dle.rae.es/mojar)* (ver acepción 8), es decir, que tome decisiones en estas colas. La cola *Low Quality Posts* ofrece dos opciones que tienen un efecto: "Looks OK" o "Delete/Recommend Deletion". Si pensáis que una respuesta no merece ser borrada, seleccionad "Looks OK" en lugar de "Skip". Del mismo modo, si pensáis que debe ser borrada, no tengáis miedo en seleccionar "Delete/Recommend Deletion". Si hay mala suerte y se acaba cometiendo un error, todo se puede deshacer si hay consenso.

Aunque se podría "no hacer nada" y decidir que las respuestas que no acumulan suficientes votos de borrado no merecen ser borradas ("presunción de inocencia"), no soy partidario de esta opción, porque esto llenará la cola de revisión y hará más difícil que las publicaciones nuevas sean revisadas.

<sup>1 Mientras no seamos un sitio no graduado, luego serán 20 000 ([referencia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)).</sup>

Comment: Que conteste a la pregunta no debería ser el único criterio para mantener una respuesta viva. [La que mencionas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37168/1674) es efectivamente respuesta, pero no aporta nada sustantivo que no se hubiera dicho ya hace años. Por tanto, yo creo que borrarla o moverla a comentarios ayuda a mantener el sitio útil y limpio (de hecho [unos cuantos lo hemos marcado como tal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/21738) y no sé si entra en contradicción con [lo que hizo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/21737) otro moderador).

Comment: Dicho lo cual, buena respuesta. Probablemente sería útil hacer un ejercicio de psicoanálisis colectivo y analizar qué queremos considerar respuesta y qué queremos hacer con las que no lo son. En definitiva, cómo queremos que se distribuya toda la información que va permeando poco a poco en todas las Q&A que reciben bastantes visitas. Creo que idealmente tendría que usarse mucho más lo de "no hacer nada" (yo la uso bastante) pues colectivamente podríamos resolverlo todo, cada uno en su especialidad. Ahora no es así.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que no hay un "problema", ya que no tardamos en dar feedback útil a un usuario nuevo o despistado que le ayude a mejorar sus contribuciones, sino que hay simplemente un poco de retraso en una tarea (comunitaria) de limpieza. Ya nos avisaréis los mods cuando finalmente los CMs hagan el cambio a 3 votos para los cierre/reopen. Añado, como menciona fedorqui, que yo personalmente sí suelo poner un flag sobre contribuciones que creo que son un "plagio" (dicen algo que ya se incluye en una respuesta preexistente y no añaden ni contenido nuevo ni explican desde un ángulo distinto)

Comment: @fedorqui Estoy de acuerdo en que "que conteste a la pregunta" no debería ser el único criterio, pero intento solo usar el *martillazo* para los casos muy claros. Otro problema es que, si la respuesta tiene un voto positivo, entonces no se puede votar para borrar, solo "Recommend Deletion", y [ni siquiera 5 votos de Recommend Deletion son suficientes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/21732). Acabo de convertir en comentario esa respuesta (donde había un claro consenso de la comunidad) y [otra no-respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37186/24236).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Para casos menos claros que esos, hará falta consenso en la comunidad...

Comment: @Diego los casos flagrantes de plagio (copy-paste) los borraría directamente si los encuentro. La información duplicada en respuestas con distinto texto prefiero dejársela a la comunidad (como el cierre de preguntas como duplicados). Dicho esto, estoy de acuerdo en que somos rápidos en dar feedback (y tú contribuyes mucho a eso, lo cual agradezco). Sobre el tema de tres votos de cierre, sigue el *radio silence* por parte de SE. Es probable que hayas acertado con la predicción de que los sombreros llegarán antes...

Comment: Sí, ya lo veo anunciado y veo el iconito del copo de nieve. Aunque el Winter Bash es una funcionalidad recurrente (puede haber algún sombrero nuevo, pero casi toda la infraestructura debe estar ya ahí de años pasados) y el cambio a 3 votos para las colas de revisión es algo nuevo, es desmoralizador. No me voy a poner en plan [cuñao](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19090/5481) a decir si debe ser fácil de implementar o no, o a qué deberían darle prioridad, pero creo que llevamos ya más un año desde que lo pedimos. Yo creo que me voy a poner el gorrito de hibernar por un tiempo.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether this should be a new question as a feature request but it seem relevant here.

When I see posts in the low quality queue the thing I really miss is any way of recommending that they be converted into a comment. I know this is possible because I often see posts deleted with a note that they were converted. This means I have to flag as not an answer which generates a message which some users found unhelpful and indeed rather aggressive. The problem is worse for me because my written Spanish is so weak that if the answer is in Spanish I do not feel I can leave a custom designed comment as it might be misunderstood. If it is in English then I can write a suitable comment.

I am not sure if there is any solution to this but it seemed worth raising.

Comment: This was [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71284/643262) ages ago, and [status-completed] without being actually completed. Only mods can convert answers to comments. It should be done only when the post is [worth preserving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74160/643262) because it has useful information. This does happen often here, and I can think of two options for you: you can add a comment on the answer saying that it should be a comment, or you can flag for moderator attention. The automatic comment "From Review" can, as far as I know, be disabled when you do the review.

Comment: You are, of course, welcome to posts comments in English under answers in Spanish. Even though the answerer *could* have some problems understanding English, this is not often the case and your self-designed comment is anyway better than the automatic comment.